# Minimize same placed elements in a list of permutations (Heap)

Tags: optimization, permutations

I'm trying to optimize the permutations generated from a set of n elements.

Here is the pitch:
I have a set of 6 elements $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and I want to create 10 permutations. I could use Heap algorithm to keep 10 among 6! possible combinations.

But I'd like to add specific constraint : I want to select the 10 permutations that **minimize the number of elements at the same index**.
(avoid having 10 permutations with the 3 at the same index for example)

For instance, I simply create the first 6 permutations by rotating my initial set from 1 to 6 to the right to obtain the following combinations: $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, $\{2,3,4,5,6,1\}$, $\{3,4,5,6,1,2\}$, $\{4,5,6,1,2,3\}$, $\{5,6,1,2,3,4\}$, $\{6,1,2,3,4,5\}$

Now, I would like to generate additional combinations following my constraint, do you have any clue or advice ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial guess, based on some cursory knowledge about [Permutohedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutohedron):

Given your set $S = {1,2,3,...}$, generate all permutations $P(S)$ and define a multigraph $G(V,E)$ where $V = P(S)$ (each permutation is a vertex) and the edge-set $E$ consists of pairs of permutations that share an element at a common location (e.g. $123456$ and $123465$ are connected by $4$ edges).

Your problem is then picking a subset of $V' \subset V$ s.t. the subgraph induced by $V'$ has as few edges as possible.

Considerations:

- You can use a weighted graph instead of a multigraph. Replace $n$ edges with 1 edge with weight $n$. The optimization objective would then be total edge weight of the induced subgraph.
- Based on the many symmetries, I would guess that it should be possible to achieve a very good (maybe even optimal) solution with a greedy algorithm.

Possible greedy algorithm:

- Construct graph, initialize $V' = \emptyset$
- Until $|V'| = n$:

  - For each $v \in V \setminus V'$: $v^+ :=$ total weight of edges between $v$ and $w\in V'$
  - If $v^+ = 0$, add $v$ to $V'$. Else, add vertex with lowest $v^+$.

Comment: Thank you for this elegant solution ! I implemented it and it works like a charm. I can probably optimize the creation of the weighted graph and the computation of the subset but I like it ! Also thanks for the reference to permutohedrons, quite interesting.